# VScode build OpenCL program fail

Tags: visual-studio-code, opencl

how to build opencl case in VScode?? The same Case I run successful in VS,but in VScode it reported clBuildProgram returned -11 , and clGetProgramBuildInfo returned empty which means CL_BUILD_NONE.
how to solve this ?

Comment: What is the command line that you use to compile?

Comment: > Executing task: g++ -g f:\wzf\VSCproject\main.cpp -o F:\wzf\VSCproject\Debugger\main.exe -I 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\include' -I 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\include\CL' -L 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\lib\x64' -l OpenCL <

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.